# Spring Cloud Stream 3 RabbitMQ consumer not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm able to make Spring+Rabbit work with the non-functional way (prior to 2.0?), but I'm trying to use with the functional pattern as the previous one is deprecated.

I've been following this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names

The queue (consumer) is not being created in Rabbit with the new method. I can see the connection being created but without any consumer.

[image]

I have the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.approved-in-0=approved
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.approved.destination=myTopic.exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.approved.group=myGroup.approved
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.approved.consumer.back-off-initial-interval=2000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.approved.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.approved.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=myRoutingKey
```

which is replacing:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.approved.destination=myTopic.exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.approved.group=myGroup.approved
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.approved.consumer.back-off-initial-interval=2000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.approved.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.approved.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=myRoutingKey
```

And the new class

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ApprovedReceiver {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> approved() {
        // I also saw that it's recommended to not use Consumer, but use Function instead
        // https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_reactive
        return value -> log.info("value: {}", value);
    }

}
```

which is replacing

```
// BindableApprovedChannel.class
@Configuration
public interface BindableApprovedChannel {
    @Input("approved")
    SubscribableChannel getApproved();
}

// ApprovedReceiver.class
@Service
@EnableBinding(BindableApprovedChannel.class)
public class ApprovedReceiver {

    @StreamListener("approved")
    public void handleMessage(String payload) {
        log.info("value: {}", payload);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple beans of type `Function`, `Supplier` or `Consumer` (which could be declared by third party libraries), the framework does not know which one to bind to.

Try setting the `spring.cloud.function.definition` property to `approved`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function

> In the event you only have single bean of type java.util.function.[Supplier/Function/Consumer], you can skip the spring.cloud.function.definition property, since such functional bean will be auto-discovered. However, it is considered best practice to use such property to avoid any confusion. Some time this auto-discovery can get in the way, since single bean of type java.util.function.[Supplier/Function/Consumer] could be there for purposes other then handling messages, yet being single it is auto-discovered and auto-bound. For these rare scenarios you can disable auto-discovery by providing spring.cloud.stream.function.autodetect property with value set to false.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post, but I tried that and it didn't work either

Comment: I just copied your code/config and it worked for me after fixing two problems - 1. The `Consumer` bean definition must be in a `@Configuration` class. not a `@Component` (e.g. `@Service`) class. 2. You can't map `approved-in-0` to `approved` because it will cause a conflict with the bean name for the message channel, you must choose a different bean name, or use `approved-in-0` in the other properties.

Comment: Or change the consumer bean name.

Comment: Ohhh, the @config vs @component/@service might have been the problem. I will check that when I have access to the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gary's answer is correct. If adding the definition property alone doesn't resolve the issue I would recommend sharing what you're doing for your supplier.

This is also a very helpful general discussion for transitioning from imperative to functional with links to repos with more in depth examples: [EnableBinding is deprecated in Spring Cloud Stream 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441549/enablebinding-is-deprecated-in-spring-cloud-stream-3-x)

Comment: I'm not doing anything for my supplier at the moment. I only setup the consumer and that alone did not create the queue in Rabbit. I tried creating the queue manually and publishing a message (also manually) and it didn't trigger any event either

Comment: Your `Consumer` bean needs to be in a `@Configuration` class; it is in a `@Service` class.